# How can we identify and filter AI-generated statements of purpose (SoP) and recommendation letters?

Tags: graduate-admissions, ethics, recommendation-letter, statement-of-purpose, generative-ai

How can we effectively identify and filter out statement of purpose (SoP) and recommendation letters that are generated by AI tools?

The authenticity of these documents is crucial for our admission process, but distinguishing AI-generated content from human-written content has become increasingly challenging. Are there any known methods, tools, or best practices for detecting AI-generated texts in academic admissions?

Additionally, how should institutions approach this issue ethically and practically, considering the rapid advancement of AI technology?

Comment: Hard to believe this is a real problem at the moment: SoPs are too personal (AI can't explain a poor grade given a particular transcript for example, especially since it doesn't know the reason), while you can always request recommendation letters from official email addresses.

Comment: Do you already have a system in place to filter fake recommendation letters written by the students themselves without the professor's approval? How does that work? Because that looks like the hardest and more important problem to me; this question might be a X-Y issue. If a recommender used AI as a writing assistant but signed the letter and confirmed that its contents are accurate, that's fine for me.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni We require recommendation letters to be submitted from an official email address not associated with the candidate. The candidate is going to have to be doing pretty well to fake a submission from i.sudbery@uni.edu

Comment: You can only identify if they use a bad model. I don't think it is possible if they use current state of the art LLMs.

Comment: @IanSudbery *"The candidate is going to have to be doing pretty well to fake a submission from i.sudbery@uni.edu"* Depending on how the sending and receiving mail servers are set up, that might not be especially hard. Without extra authentication, forging a From: header is exactly as hard as writing a bogus return address on a physical letter.

Comment: "The authenticity of these documents is crucial for our admission process" OMG really? I mean, I wrote my own myself, but I'm a terrible writer. I've been assuming the transcripts and portfolio are much more important. Hopefully the cruciality of statements of purpose is mainly for degrees related to writing.

Comment: @Ray Pretty much no university is going to be without SPF these days, and DKIM and DMARC are quite common. Those technologies make forging a header much harder. Or, I suppose forging a header is still just as easy but the receiving mail system can easily detect the forgery. Undetectable forgeries are much harder to pull off.

Comment: Why do you care? Is 'writing SOPs' a critical skill for your program? I'd hope you judge an SOP for its content, not on its writing style or the tools used to write it.

Comment: This question seems posed by an AI trying to find its own weakness ... or at least by a candidate trying to see how their own AI-generated SoP can be modified to be perceived as human generated ...

Comment: Honestly, I question whether SoPs are even a useful indicator in the admissions process

Comment: @IanSudbery you can send an email with a forged from field pretty trivially

Comment: @ScottishTapWater True, but there are ways around that. For example the application server sends the referee a message to confirm their submisison.

Comment: Is that server respecting the replyto field?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater Every system for letters that I've interacted with lately requires the letter writer to be able to *receive* email at a given address, from at which point they authenticate to the university application system. A student could submit a fake email address under their own control, but forging the from field isn't going to help them.

Comment: That's good at least

Comment: There is a nontrivial security hole in the systems used by most universities, as pointed out by @RLH. Students can put whatever they like as contact details for their referees, and that will trigger automated emails to those addresses containing a one-time login password for referees to submit their letters. There's nothing to stop a student creating a fake account named iansudbery@gmail.com or whatever and then writing a letter purporting to be from Ian Sudbery.

Comment: It would take a very sharp-eyed admissions tutor to spot that the letter came from a non-university address (particularly since academics move around a lot, and hence many genuinely do prefer to use gmail or other non-university addresses for work purposes). Universities' attempts to get around this are frequently utterly risible ("the letter must be on headed notepaper" etc, as if that wasn't trivial to fake). But this has very little to do with ChatGPT.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is no need to filter out AI-generated statements of purpose.

Even without AI, it is not reasonable to assume that applicants have generally written their SoPs all by themselves. They have received substantial input from others, or even have had someone else writing the entire thing for them. The spread of LLMs might actually be beneficial here, because it could lessen the difference between applicants with friends or family that knows how to write a good SoP and those that don't.

Contentwise, an AI-generated SoP will probably read well, but very much generic (because it is going to mimic typical examples of SoPs available on the internet). To a large extent, LLMs are bullshit generators: They create text that sounds good on first glance, but they don't really have coherent arguments. Thus, I can easily believe that a LLM can write a decent SoP, but I'd very surprised if they produce a great one.

In conclusion, if AI-generated SoPs might have a significant impact on your admissions process, there is probably something wrong with the process. The solution is to improve the admissions process, not to try and filter for AI-generated texts.

Comment: "I can easily believe that a LLM can write a decent SoP, but I'd very surprised if they produce a great one." It can actually make a good one into a generic one; those who wrote great ones always win...

Comment: One thing that seems to be creeping in - though I haven't tested it myself - is AI-assisted writing. In that case the applicant throws something together and uses an AI tool to rewrite it (often in more formal language).  I wonder how the OP would perceive that.  Is it just a spelling/grammar checker with a sense of superiority?

Comment: @ChrisH What i'm looking for in an SoP for a PhD student is that the student is actaully intrested in working specifically with me, understands what it we do in my lab, and specifically keen this particular project. For a job, and SoP can help the assesor map evidence of skills/experiences to job criteria. Good writing can help me see that if its true, but it can't hide its absence.

Comment: While likely to improve in the future, I think your description as a "bullshit generator" is right on presently. I, along with many others, have spoken and written about how the use of LLM in a legal context can be very dangerous unless the LLM's output is carefully monitored and vetted by a qualified legal professional.

Comment: Most humans writing is also akin to a bullshit generator. Just compare the average Quora answer to the average StackExchange answer. The former often make no sense at all or don't actually answer the question.

Comment: "There is no need to filter out AI-generated statements of purpose."  For programs that get a lot of applicants, one of the reasons to require a statement of purpose is to reduce the number of applicants by increase the work required to apply.  If the statement of purpose can be "AI" generated, then the number of applicants might increase.  So, in some cases, there is a need impose some kind of burden that an "AI" cannot remove.

Comment: @JonathanReez That's my favorite laughter about LLM criticism. "They don't know what they are really talking about" is about the most common criticism of human writing as well...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica it's almost as if the LLM critics don't know what they're really talking about! :D

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally, how should institutions approach this issue ethically and practically, considering the rapid advancement of AI technology?

If an AI can do a great job for a given student output and in-person examination is not possible, the only feasible solution is to just drop them as a requirement altogether. Use other criteria to evaluate the candidates, as you can no longer rely on people's essay writing skills to be the deciding factor.

Some people have mentioned that current LLMs cannot output *great* essays and I agree they can't beat the best 10% of humans just yet, but new versions of AI software are coming out every year and it's reasonable to believe that by 2030 AI will be able to write better essays than 99% of all humans. You might as well put yourself ahead of the curve and stop grading people for work that's best delegated to a machine.

Comment: "but new versions of AI software are coming out every year" - MONTH, not year. " it's reasonable to believe that by 2030 AI will be able to write better essays than 99% of all humans." - make that 2025. 2024 if someone puts focus on that.

Comment: @TomTom eh, I'm a huge fan of ChatGPT but I think that the 90%->99% gap will take a long time to cross. The 99%->100% will take even longer.

Comment: Nah, see, humans are not really 100% on top - the best are, not others. Also, history shows that it does not take long and then humans are left in the dust. Plenty of AI research examples demonstrating that and now they are putting them into AI LLM's. Check the history of the AI GO players to see what is coming. Or the AI poker player research, or the AI Diplomacy research (that is a game, actually, heavy on negotiations). All demonstrated total AI dominance.

Comment: @TomTom Wanna bet $1000 on this not happening within the next 1 year? At what odds? Money talks, everything else walks ;)

Comment: What about a SENSIBLE bet? And stop toy money. Seroiusly, 1 year is irrelevant - we talk about career ending and you say "oh, tomorrow". What about 3-5 years? Still willing to put your money (and please, REAL money, not a tip) where your mouth is? Btw., if money talks - you are a mouse unheard, $1000 -  joke.